# How to read textfile with some words in python

Tags: python, string, file

i'm new in python please kindly help my stuck, i have code like bellow:

```
fobj = open("data.txt") 
text = fobj.read().strip().split()
```

## Conditions

```
while True:
    s = input("Enter a string: ") #Takes input of a string from user
    if s == "": #if no value is entered for the string
        continue
    if s in text: #string in present in the text file
        print(s)
        break
    else: #string is absent in the text file
        print("No such string found,try again")
        continue fobj.close()
```

If i search in complete word in file .txt the result is ok, but if i search  some word, my result "No such string found,try again"

example :

```
Enter a string: oke
oke

> ================================ RESTART ================================
>
Enter a string: ok
No such string found,try again
```

i want if i write "ok" the result must be "oke bla bla" with one line
kindly please help my stuck, thanks in advance

Comment: `fobj.read().strip().split()` splits your entire string (read from the file), by whitespace into a list of string tokens. Hence, anything you enter via `input` will have to be compared in a similar fashion. Remove the `split`, and in theory you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem comes from the fact that you've read in the text from your file and split it by whitespace.** Doing so tokenizes your text by whitespace from a string, into a list of strings.

e.g. `"This is a test".split()` becomes `["this", "is", "a", "test"]`

Hence, any input that you've read via `input`, a full string, will either have to be split and compared in a similar fashion.

The simplest thing to do would be to not `split` on whitespace, and your comparison should work as intended.

Comment: you mean, i must be write one  sentence in input?

Comment: @adeirawan: no - I meant: your file must be read in as a single string - i.e. change `text = fobj.read().strip().split()` to `text = fobj.read().strip()`

Comment: i want to if i do input one word the result must be one line. what should i do in my code

Comment: @adeirawan: if I'm understanding you correctly (and please correct me if I'm wrong), you have a file of text across several lines. You want to know if you enter a word, which line of the text file contains the word you entered via `input`. Is that correct?

Comment: yess via input.. i have change your advice, yeah its work  but the result not complete suitable with my file.txt

Comment: @adeirawan: I'm sorry, but I'm not following you - what do you mean exactly? If possible, could you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i have sample like this:

term = "mod"
file = open('data2.txt')
for line in file:
    line.strip().split('/n')
    if term in line:
        print (line)
file.close()

i want to the word "mod" created by input.

contens file data2.txt like bellow:

MemTotal,5,2016-07-30 12:02:33,781
model name,3,2016-07-30 13:37:59,074
model,3,2016-07-30 15:39:59,075
model,21928
model

Comment: @adeirawan: This question seems to be different than the one you posed. It may be better to post it as a separate question, referencing this one.